# a:hover not working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, mouseover

**Edit: refreshing without cache solves the issue..**

For some reason, no a:hover in my css is working anymore. I have no idea why not. (It's a theme for tumblr, [this](http://potter.tumblr.com/) web page, full code [here](http://pastebin.com/VZYDzugN).) The regular a properties work fine, but whatever I write in the a:hover, the links don't change on mouseover.

```
a {color: {color:Text link}; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-style:italic; 
letter-spacing:0.1em;}

a:hover {color: {color:Text link hover};}
```

edit: it's supposed to be weird, it used to work until I apparently changed something that got it all wrong - but if I use the following code the hover still doesn't work:

```
a {color: red;}
a:hover {color: blue;}
```

Coding is about the same for different classes. I'm not using the classes anywhere else in the code so I don't see how it could be overriden, and I've tried adding !important, but that doesn't work. The only classes for which the hover is working, are .desclink and .post.

Comment: it's not working, beacuse you are using <meta> color for this hover parameter. Use simple color:red;

Comment: I see in the element inspectation, that it works, but color in the css is grey on hover, and is grey before hover... make it different color on your page, user1501459

Comment: Did you tried `color:blue !important` ?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/ to test your css

Comment: Your code has got lots of errors http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpotter.tumblr.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: can't, it must be hosted on tumblr, there are properties like blocks that are supported by the tumblr coding.. system.. or something. You can't use it to make a web page from scratch, there are certain elements like the meta properties and the {block:if...}s that are specifically for tumblr.com

Answer (score 2):

```
a {
color:red;
text-decoration:none; 
font-style:italic; 
letter-spacing:0.1em;
}

a:hover {color: blue;}
```

try this one

Comment: I've tried. It doesn't change to blue. The a:hover simply isn't working.

Comment: It doesn't work because it needs to be hosted on tumblr, there are customizable aspects like the meta properties that don't work unless it's on a tumblr account page. That's why the coding looks so strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is wrong, here is the right one.

```
a {color:Black;//Color you want for link 
text-decoration:none; 
font-style:italic; 
letter-spacing:0.1em;}

a:hover {color:Red; }//Color on hover
```

Comment: okay no what I'm doing probably looks weird but it's supposed to be like that for the tumblr interface, take a look at what Miqdad wrote, if I use the "right" properties the hover still doesn't work.

Comment: If I do that, it still doesn't work. I've tried. The hover properties are ignored, no matter what I put there, no matter which colour I try to make it.

Comment: Try to refresh page without cache, ctrl+R, ctrl+F5

Comment: Working! ..How is that possible?

Comment: Thank you very much! But why? What does that mean?

Comment: okay I'm stupid I can't figure out how to upvote your comment

Comment: ah. I can't vote up because I'm a new user. Sorry. But thanks again!